# GitLab CI incomplete output of job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When a job fails, the end of the output seems truncated:

```
$ yum install curl -y
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

If I re-run the same job on the same code / commit manually by pressing "retry", then the output appears:

```
$ yum install curl -y
/bin/sh: eval: line 84: yum: not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

As you can see the second line is the most important: it shows the error message. How to get full output always?

.gitlab-ci.yml (the line is in 'before_script' so I don't add jobs here):

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

before_script:
    - olddir=$(pwd)
    - yum install curl -y
```

No docker image specified.

Comment: please attach .gitlab.yaml and docker image

Comment: @NaorTedgi Added, thank you. No docker image specified, I assume default one but how can I check which one is in use?

Comment: if you have no docker image specified so why you are sure that yum is install on your runner ?

Comment: Problem is not in yum but in missed error message.